# Access to parent from embedded document on creation (Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid

This trick works with "has_many" relation, but fails with "embeds_many". Any ideas?

```
class Country
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
    embeds_many :cities  
end

class City
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
    field :full_name, type: String, default: ->{ "#{name}, #{country.name}" }
    embedded_in :country
end


1.9.3p392 :025 > c = Country.find_or_create_by(name: 'foo')
 => #<Country _id: foo, name: "foo"> 

1.9.3p392 :026 > c.cities.find_or_create_by(name: 'bar')
NoMethodError: undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass
```

So, it fails on a line "field :full_name, type: String, default: ->{ "#{name}, #{country.name}" }" becouse country is undefined for that moment

Comment: The error message "undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass" doesn't fit with your explanation of the default. If you remove the default, does it pass?

Comment: yes its pass. undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass means country is nil

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `country` first, then it will return `country.name`

`field :full_name, type: String, default: ->{ "#{name}, " << country.name if country }`

I could not get this to work with string interpolation, but append works (which concatenates country.name to str)